# How to create drag and drop Divs based persistent web page in ASP.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql, ajax, json

In my web page I have to create a timetable , where user can drag and drop subjects from subject list, teachers from teacher list and room nos from room no list to a table cell or div  and i want to save this configuration in database also. 
Like which cell(period) , which subject/faculty/room no had being dropped.

I want to achieve this in jQuery using ASP.net and SQL server.

Should I user ASP.net Web Parts Control to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had to do something similar a while ago, i used the following, might be helpful to you:

http://www.redips.net/javascript/drag-and-drop-table-content/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, web parts are perfect for this scenario.